# Data not inserting in database when submitted

Tags: php, html, database

I've set up a form to insert data into a database. It's connected to it fine and can display records with no issues. However, when I want to insert data I click the submit button it removes it from the form but doesn't insert it into the db. I've tried rewriting it about 3 times now using 2 different databases but just can't figure out where I'm going on.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
<form action="input.php" meathod="post">
Username: <input type="text" name="username"><br>
Password: <input type="text" name="password"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>


<?php 
if( isset($_POST['submit'])){

//connecting to a databse
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
mysqli_select_db("test",$conn);

if($conn){
        echo 'connected';
    }
    else {
        die('failed to connect');
    }

$sql="INSERT INTO users(username,password) VALUES ('$_POST[username]','$_POST[password]')"; 

mysql_query($sql,$conn);

mysqli_close($conn);
};  
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Stop mixing `mysqli_` and `mysql_` calls - `mysql_query` for example.

Comment: `$sql="INSERT INTO users(username,password) VALUES ('" . $_POST[username] . "','" . $_POST[password] . "')"; `And you should use dots.

Comment: `meathod="post"` ??? typo - should be `method`  so probably resorting to a GET request

Comment: Also - use prepared statements and bind variables - and most importantly is NOT to store plane passwords in the database.

Comment: You  have an SQL injection vulnerability.

Answer (score 1):

You have few typos `"meathod=post"` should be `method="post"`,`mysql_query($sql,$conn)` should be `mysqli_query($conn,$sql)` and `mysqli_select_db("test",$conn)` should be `mysqli_select_db($conn,"test")`

```
 <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form action="input.php" method="post">
    Username: <input type="text" name="username"><br>
    Password: <input type="text" name="password"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
    </form>
    <?php 
    if( isset($_POST['submit'])){
    //connecting to a databse
    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysqli_select_db($conn,"test");
    if($conn){
            echo 'connected';
        }
        else {
            die('failed to connect');
        }
    $sql="INSERT INTO users(username,password) VALUES ('" . $_POST['username'] . "','" . $_POST['password'] . "')"; 
    mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    mysqli_close($conn);
    };  
    ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is here

```
mysql_query($sql,$conn);
```

Replace with

```
mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
```

Comment: it should be mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

Answer (score 0):

you have written "meathod=post" instead of "method=post"
also I have changed

```
$sql="INSERT INTO users(username,password) VALUES ('$_POST[username]','$_POST[password]')";
```

to

```
$sql="INSERT INTO users(username,password) VALUES ('" . $_POST['username'] . "','" . $_POST['password'] . "')";
```

this style much more better

```
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
<form action="lol.php" method="post">
Username: <input type="text" name="username"><br>
Password: <input type="text" name="password"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>


<?php 
if( isset($_POST['submit'])){

//connecting to a databse
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
mysqli_select_db("test",$conn);

if($conn){
        echo 'connected';
    }
    else {
        die('failed to connect');
    }

$sql="INSERT INTO users(username,password) VALUES ('" . $_POST['username'] . "','" . $_POST['password'] . "')"; 

mysql_query($sql,$conn);

mysqli_close($conn);
};  
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: also you must change mysql_query to mysqli_query

Answer (score 0):

I hope this code will help you

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>

    <body>
    <form action="input.php" method="post">
    Username: <input type="text" name="username"><br>
    Password: <input type="text" name="password"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
    </form>


    <?php 
    if( isset($_POST['submit'])){

    //connecting to a databse
    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysqli_select_db("test",$conn);

    if($conn){
            echo 'connected';
        }
        else {
            die('failed to connect');
        }

  $sql="INSERT INTO users(username,password) VALUES (".$_POST["username"].",".$_POST["password"].")"; 

    mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    mysqli_close($conn);

    ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: meathod="post" ??

Comment: oh.thank you .I did not pay attention to it:-).I give you a positive vote.